# This member is defined more than once

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have looked at all the other member defined more than once threads and could not find one that was like mine.  If there is one and I missed it I am sorry.  Most of what we do here is VB.NET, but I am trying to convert some existing code to C#.  The problem I am having is I am getting a "This member is defined more than once" Here is my code.

```
private System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection mSqlConn;
private bool mLoadOnly = false;

public void New(bool isLoadOnly) {

        mLoadOnly = isLoadOnly;

        mSqlConn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(GetConnStr());

    }
```

So I get the error in the constructor.  I do not see how I am defining mLoadOnly or mSqlConn again.  I am trying to define these as class wide variables, but C# does not seem to like this.  How should I go about doing this? Thank you!

Comment: What line is the compiler complaining about? Are you sure you copied the exact code or are you missing something (readonly keyword?)

Comment: Can you paste the exact error and the line # is refers to?

Comment: What is the class called? a constructor should not be a `void`

Comment: Well I got the red squiggle line underneath both mLoadOnly and mSqlConn.  As someone has stated the constructor is defined wrong so I am going to have to fix that and see if it alleviates some issues.

Comment: As a side note, which converter are you using? I noticed if using developer fusion, the best is to convert at class level. If you try to feed method names, such as the constructor, it will not be converted properly.

Comment: I will take that into consideration because I have just been putting it in methods at a time.  I have been trying to do it by hand though and trying to learn as much about C# as I possibly can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have the constructor defined multiple times in your code file. Also, constructors in C# are declared differently, i.e.

```
public ClassName(...)
```

Check this article on MSDN:

- [Using Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx)

Comment: I was unaware of constructors being defined differently.  I just know in VB it was Public Sub New(ByVal isLoadOnly As Boolean) so I when I translated it I just called it a public void which obviously was wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Well the answer you gave fixed an issue with my constructor, but did not fix the actual issue I was having with the "This member is defined more than once".  Underneath that it says "Error Ambiguity between 'DBOps.Connections.BaseDBConn.mSqlConn' and 'DBOps.Connections.BaseDBConn.mSqlConn'"  If I put the data type in before either mSqlConn or mLoadOnly it goes away, but not sure if that is the right way to do it. Thanks again!

Comment: @j5juice: Can you post the whole class?

Comment: Possibly. I do not have the whole class converted yet, and it is pretty big.  I did add an _ in front of the variables and it seems to have taken the error away.  So now they are _mSqlConn and _mLoadOnly.  I will try and post the whole class here soon though.

Comment: @j5juice: You can post only the part which is relevant to the question, i.e. reduce your conversion to pieces, so that they are small enough to publish, and also good enough to illustrate the problem.